# Moodle: Hide "Your site is not yet registered" message

Tags: moodle

I am on Moodle 3.10 on IIS. I am trying to hide the message that popups: "Your site is not yet registered".

I once edited a php and commented it out, but since a recent upgrade I lost it and it is back. I don't remember which file or area I updated to hide this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the file `moodle/admin/search.php`

Then find and comment the line `echo $adminrenderer->warn_if_not_registered();`, the line number should be 56.

The end result should look like this.

```
53 // Display a warning if site is not registered.
54 if (empty($query)) {
55    $adminrenderer = $PAGE->get_renderer('core', 'admin');
56    //echo $adminrenderer->warn_if_not_registered();
57 }
```

Comment: With the next moodle update this hack is gone :)

Answer (score 2):

If you add:

```
CFG->site_is_public = false;
```

into your config.php (in the moodle directory) then the reminder is not displayed.